# Facebook App: How do I cause new chat messages to appear minimized?

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-canvas, facebook-chat

When my user is messaged while using my app, is there a way to make the chat window appear minimized rather than auto-opening?  It appears uberstrike: https://apps.facebook.com/uberstrike/ has some way of doing this. I cannot find where this is being done in the JS on that page though.  What I can say is the following:

When examining the difference between the minimized and non-minimzed (uberstrike vs FB profile page) the div which is the title of the chat has the classes:

uberstrike: fbNub _50-v _50mz *50m* _5238 highlightTab highlightTitle

fb profile page: fbNub _50-v _50mz *50m* _5238 highlightTab opened highlightTitle

The only difference is the inclusion of the "opened" class. Additionally, when I delve deeper into the HTML I see that there is a table which represents the contents of the chat window.  In Uberstrike, the discussion doesn't even populate while on my profile page, there are many  tags containing the discussion.

This leads me to believe that there must be some setting to convince FB to treat this game's page differently.  I would like to know how to cause my application to behave the same way.